# Reset Touchpad driver

Tags: mouse, touchpad, input

My Synaptics touchpad on my laptop running Ubuntu 18.04 recently stopped working. It's not a hardware problem; when running the same version of Ubuntu from a flash drive it works fine. That makes it either a configuration problem or a problem from an update. Unfortunately, it was running with a usb mouse for a while, so it would be hard to test if a update broke it.

I have been trying to debug it and reset the settings for it. I have

- Reset dconf
- Found the device on xinput, it appears to be configured correctly
- Used xinput test to listen for events, and got nothing
- Found the device on /proc/bus/input/devices, it appears to be configured correctly
- Used evtest to listen for events and got nothing

What else can I do to debug my touchpad? What other settings could be interfering that I could reset?

Comment: use xinput and evtest on the working Ubuntu just for comparison ... also, plug in an external mouse and test mouse and touchpad, then unplug mouse and test touchpad ... do test in the working and nonworking distributions